# Naked custom domain stopped working

Tags: google-app-engine

I have had a custom domain pointing to my appengine app for a long while now. Today the naked domain stoped working (get google's 404 page). ie mydomain.com no longer works where as www.mydomain.com works. DNS entries are correct ( I have multiple domains attached to the same appengine app and they all work except for one).

Comment: In case anyone runs into this. I never figured out what the problem was. Ended up removing the custom domain from the app and adding it again.

Comment: Did re-adding it without any other action fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, took about 10 mins for DNS to sort itself.